# Copy specific cells based on value in the same row in sheet1(table1) and paste into sheet2(table2) next available row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

This code works, but it puts the values at the bottom of Sheet2(Table2), instead of next available row in table2. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fZ6GLGtVNd13I-GTgLVjnfKlzrwx05U/view?usp=sharing

Sub Macro()

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim s As Long
  Dim myRow As Long
          
                   
      s = ws.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
              
      LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
                     
          For myRow = 2 To LastRow
              If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "I") = "INACTIVE" Then
                 ws.Range("A" & s + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "A")
                 ws.Range("B" & s + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "B")
                 ws.Range("C" & s + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "C")
                 ws.Range("D" & s + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow, "I")
              End If
          Next myRow
```

End Sub

Comment: your s variable remains constant, - so code keeps overwriting values on top...
simply place `s = ws.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` inside the loop (after 'For myRow = 2 To LastRow')

Comment: I'm still getting the same results when I placed your suggestion, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Copying Data From One Excel Table to Another

- Dealing with Excel tables in VBA can be quite tricky. This is a simple user-friendly version. You could dive much deeper into it by using (an array of) the table headers in the loop and whatnot.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = sws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dtbl As ListObject: Set dtbl = dws.ListObjects("Table2")

    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim srrg As Range
    Dim drrg As Range
    Dim r As Long
    
    For Each sCell In stbl.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange
        r = r + 1
        If StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), "INACTIVE", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set srrg = stbl.ListRows(r).Range
            Set drrg = dtbl.ListRows.Add.Range
            drrg.Cells(1).Value = srrg.Cells(1).Value
            drrg.Cells(2).Value = srrg.Cells(2).Value
            drrg.Cells(3).Value = srrg.Cells(3).Value
            drrg.Cells(4).Value = srrg.Cells(9).Value
        End If
    Next sCell

End Sub
```

Comment: in my case, while testing VBasic2008's code, - if table2 has 1st empty row, it stays empty

Comment: @Rolandas Kol: If it has a hundred empty rows, they will stay empty. The trick is when the table is empty (although one row is always showing) that the first row will be added.

Comment: @Patrick: You can give Rolandas Kol (or me additionally) an upvote by clicking the up arrow to the left of his post if his answer was also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the below code should work as `s` variable is inside the loop.

P.S.

Updated the code to match your example.
Also, the sheet2 has table, so the last row was not detected correctly by `End(xlUp).Row`

The problem was also with `myRow =2`

```
Sub Macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim s As Long
Dim myRow As Long
          
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
           
For myRow = 1 To LastRow
    s = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    If ws1.Cells(myRow, "I") = "INACTIVE" Then
        ws.Range("A" & s & ":C" & s) = ws1.Range("A" & myRow & ":C" & myRow).Value
        ws.Range("D" & s) = "INACTIVE"
    End If
Next myRow
                  
MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: That is where I placed it, is there a way to share this workbook on here? I made an example workbook.

Comment: just drop it into gdrive or similar, - and share the link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fZ6GLGtVNd13I-GTgLVjnfKlzrwx05U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Still the same, still places values at the bottom of the table. Is it working for you? You got me thinking something is wrong with my excel.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the type of problem you having...
Does my code creates new rows, but your Table is not expanding accordingly?

Comment: Updated once again... sorry I am not a pro... still do the mistakes...
it is my approach, a bit different, but does the job

Comment: It is not filling in the next available row in table, it is placing it underneath the table instead. I have tried .offset(-1,0) as well, that will replace the headers.

Comment: Try the last, updated one.

Comment: Hey no problem, any suggestions is deeply appreciated. So now the update code is now placing the values in the table, but not adding to next row. I tried something like that earlier and got the same result.

Comment: Got it!
As sheet2 had table, last row was not detected using `End(xlUp).Row`
I have updated the code to find last row in the different manner, - I hope it does the job :)